# Numpy way to temporarily remove NaN values from array, with ability to place them back later

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get a version of an array without the NaN values, with the ability to place them back later. Example:

```py
Array = [1,2,nan,4,5,2,5,6,nan,1,nan,nan,nan,nan,8,7,5,2]
Array_non_nan = [1,2,4,5,2,5,6,1,8,7,5,2]
```

This can be achieved with array[~np.isnan(array)]. However now I want to be able to remember the locations of the NaN values, and place them back later.

I tried:

```py
array = np.array([nan,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5., nan,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])  
no_nan= array[~np.isnan(array)]      
locs = (np.argwhere(np.isnan(array))).flatten()      
original_array = np.insert(no_nan, obj = locs, values = np.NaN)
```

However in that case the insertion is unsuccesfull because of a problem with the indexing:

```
array([nan,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6., nan,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

I need a vectorized solution, simply writing a loop would be to slow.

Comment: Please use code formatting, not block quotes, for code

Comment: Why not just keep the original array? it probably doesn't take much more space than your `locs` array. Or just generate `no_nan` when you need it?

Comment: If instead of trying to insert the NaNs back you overwrite the non-NaNs, would that work for you? Then you don't have problems with indexing.

Comment: I am creating a neural network, and do not want to have the NaN data in the training data for it. However, the data originally is a grid, and I do want to be able to transform it back to this grid after the neural network makes the prediction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the indices where the `nan` values existed via as a boolean mask.  Then use that mask to fill in the the value you want.

```
a = np.array([nan,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5., nan,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])  
nan_mask = np.isnan(a)
a_no_nan = a[~nan_mask]
```

So far it is basically what you have.  If you want to push the values of `a_no_nan` to a new array with same shape as `a`, but keep the `nan` locations, you can create an empty array, fill it with `nan` values, then push values using the mask.

```
c = np.empty_like(a)
c.fill(np.nan)
c[~nan_mask] = a_no_nan
c
# returns:
array([nan,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5., nan,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

Comment: What about if I have a 2D array? 
c[~nan_mask] = a_no_nan is not preserving the shape

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the solution. You store the ids and you can insert it back when needed. However I would higly reccomend the other options the other users are suggesting. Store it somewhere or deepcopy

```
Array = [1,2,np.nan,4,5,2,5,6,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,8,7,5,2]
Array_non_nan = [x for x in Array if not np.isnan(x)]
list_id = [id_ for id_,elem_ in enumerate(Array) if np.isnan(elem_) ]
for id_ in list_id:
    Array_non_nan.insert(id_, np.nan)
```

Comment: You really should avoid for loops when using numpy if possible.  They are slow performance a lot.

Comment: I would be interested to know why if you can develop a little more @James

Comment: The numpy operations take place in the C layer, and are optimized and very fast; for loops are handled by the Python layer and are much slower by comparison.  If you only have a small amount of data, it won't matter, but for large arrays a for-loop is extremely slow by comparison